# CSS bottom 0 aligns to outside of div

Tags: html, css

When I try to fix a div to the bottom of a wrapper div with `position: absolute`, `bottom: 0`, the div is aligned to the outside bottom of the div, ending up below and outside it. This means that if the wrapper extends to the bottom of the page that my div's child is not even visible. Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Can you had a fiddle of your project or your code ?

Comment: set `position:relative` to the parent div , this may fixed your issue

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your proper than please try this one.

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.wrapper div {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The parent div has position relative already, that's why I was confused as to how this behavior can happen

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `position: relative` to the parent div and to the wrapper you 
should give `position: absolute`.

Comment: The parent div has position relative already, that's why I was confused as to how this behavior can happen

Answer (score 0):

Just give parent`position: relative;` where you want to adjust that child div

```css
.parent{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.child{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color:white
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   Div At Bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent div has position relative already, that's why I was confused as to how this behavior can happen